# Como criar um polígono no gráfico nmds usando ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Eu estou tentando criar um polígono mas não consigo deixar ele preenchido e completo.

```
geral<-read.csv2("flora.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = T);head(geral)

comgeral = geral[,4:ncol(geral)]

m_comg = as.matrix(comgeral)

set.seed(123)

nmdsg = metaMDS(m_comg, distance = "bray");nmdsg

data.scoresg = as.data.frame(scores(nmdsg))



data.scoresg$rio = geral$rio
data.scoresg$tipologia = geral$tipologia


nmdsg= ggplot(data.scoresg, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2, col=rio)) +  geom_polygon(data.scoresg, aes (fill = rio , group = rio))
  geom_point(size = 3, aes( shape = tipologia, colour = rio))+ stat_ellipse() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 10, face = "plain"), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", face = "plain", size = 10), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10, face ="plain", colour ="black"), 
        legend.position = "right", axis.title.y = element_text(face = "plain", size = 10), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(face = "plain", size = 10, colour = "black"), 
        legend.title = element_text(size = 10, colour = "black", face = "plain"), 
        panel.background = element_blank(), panel.border = element_rect(colour = "darkgray", fill = NA, size = 1.2),
        legend.key=element_blank()) + 
  labs(x = "NMDS1", colour = "Área", y = "NMDS2", shape = "Tipologia florestal") + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("green","purple")) 

 

nmdsg
```

Comment: Bem-vinda ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Complementando o comentário de @marcus-nunes, se a sua questão não depende dos seus dados especificadamente, pode usar algum dos datasets inclusos no R de exemplo. Pode, por exemplo, usar o conjunto `varespec` do pacote *vegan*. Aproveitando o assunto, inclua no início do código postado as bibliotecas que está usando(*ggplot2* e *vegan*), assim como nas tags. E remova a tag "rstudio", já que sua pergunta não é sobre ele.